# Produce all combinations of one element with all other elements within a single column in R

Tags: r, combn

Suppose I have a data frame with a single column that contains letters a, b, c, d, e.

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

In R, is it possible to extract a single letter, such as 'a', and produce all possible paired combinations between 'a' and the other letters (with no duplications)? Could the `combn` command be used in this case?

```
a b
a c
a d
a e
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `data.frame`

```
data.frame(col1 = 'a', col2 = setdiff(df1$V1, "a"))
```

-ouptput

```
col1 col2
1    a    b
2    a    c
3    a    d
4    a    e
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Brilliant @akrun! Could you explain briefly what the setdiff command does here?

Comment: @LyricalStats9 thanks.  `setdiff` removes the element 'a' from the unique elements of 'V1' columns

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**
With `.before=1` argument the code is shorter :-)

```
df %>% 
  mutate(col_a = first(col1), .before=1) %>%
  slice(-1)
```

With `dplyr` you can:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(col2 = first(col1)) %>%
  slice(-1) %>% 
  select(col2, col1)
```

Output:

```
  col2  col1 
  <chr> <chr>
1 a     b    
2 a     c    
3 a     d    
4 a     e
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```r
expand.grid(x=df[1,], y=df[2:5,])
```

which returns

```
  x y
1 a b
2 a c
3 a d
4 a e
```